# How can i switch multiple layer with same sprite?

Tags: andengine, layer

I have 6 sprites on screen, now after particular time, I want to reload that 6 sprites without affecting screen. (with removing old & add new images)

like objects are changing in one frame.

I use Layers for this, but I am not able to assign two same sprite in both layers.
How can I switch multiple layer with same sprite?

Answer (score 0):

got the answer.

just detach current layer.

initialize next layer.

overwrite ArrayList (in my case, i have taken arraylist of sprite) of sprite with required images.

attach that arraylist to newly created layer & then attach that layer to scene.